# Quick Fix J how to send Server Name Indication (SNI)

Tags: java, ssl, sni, quickfixj

I am running a QFJ initiator engine with core 2.3.1 and connecting to an acceptor using SSL (SocketUseSSL=Y), I want to send an SNI, I saw that there is a flag UseSNI but how can you add the server name?
If I am using SocketConnectHost to connect to the server, where do I add the internal address in the server (SNI)

Comment: As per https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/blob/dce91e62c7525b84448b974b796a1fac436015ae/quickfixj-core/src/main/java/quickfix/mina/ssl/SSLFilter.java#L68 it automatically sends the remote address.